# $f$ is analytic, prove that for all $z$ with $|z|=1$, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty|a_nz^n|\leq 2\max\{|f(z)|:|z|=2\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Prove that for all $z$ with $|z|=1$, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty|a_nz^n|\leq 2 \max\{|f(z)|:|z|=2\}$.

My try: I have no idea about how to prove it. I guess it can proved by Cauchy estimates or use the relation
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^n(0)}{n!}z^n.
$$

Comment: Are you sure you transcribed the homework correctly?

Comment: @copper.hat I am sure the HW is written like this. I totally have no idea how to bound the $\sum_{n=0}^\infty|a_nz^n|$.

Comment: Try Cauchy's integral formula and note that if $|z| \le 1$ and $|w| = 2$ then $|z-w| \ge 1$.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was misleading and would only show that $|\sum_n a_n|$ is bounded by the quantity in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the right track with a Cauchy estimate approach. For $n=0,1,\dots,$

$$a_n = \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=2}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}\,dz.$$

Let $M= \max_{|z|=2}|f(z)|.$ From the above, $|a_n| \le \dfrac{M}{2^n}.$ Thus

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n| \le M\cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-n} = 2M.$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. Notice that $f$ entire is not needed; we only need $f$ analytic on $D(0,2+\epsilon).$